# Thin Client Laptop

Tags: laptop, thin-client

I would like a recommendation on a thin client laptop.

### Requirements

- Under $150
- 1280 x 720 screen
- Capable of decoding video at 720p@60fps
- 802.11ac WiFi
- Less than 2" thick
- at least 60GB hard drive
- 4hr general usage battery life
- USB
- 13.3" screen

### Preferences

- 15" screen
- 1920 x 1080 screen
- Capable of decoding video at 1080p@60fps
- Ethernet
- 1" thick
- SSD
- Speaker & microphone

It will be used for streaming games from another desktop and surfing the web.

The **laptop** will surf the web.

The **desktop** will play games and **stream** them to the **laptop**.

Answer (score 1):

NZKshatriya is correct - the price you're asking for is a little unrealistic for the system you want. However, if we go looking outside that range a way, there are plenty of systems you could have instead.

The Acer Aspire series has served me well, in particular the **[Acer Aspire E1-570](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/SI/content/model/NX.MGUEX.001)**:

- (+) 1366x768 screen resolution
- (+) Will happily decode 1080/60 video
- (+) 1 Ethernet port
- (-) Only supports 802.11 b/g/n WiFi; not ac.
- (0) Definitely under 2" thick; not sure about 1"
- (0) 500 GB hard drive
- (+) 5+ hours battery life
- (+) 2x USB 2.0 and 1x USB 3.0 ports
- (+) 15.6" screen
- (+) Speaker and microphone; microphone range isn't great but quality is.

also:

- 4 GB RAM, upgradable to 8 GB (DDR3)
- SD card reader built-in

I bought mine for around £300, which would have been $450 then but is $369 now.

Comment: I will second his recommendation.  Adding more ram, or an SSD would be a non issue with this one, seeing as Acer thought well enough to actually have access panels over them.

Comment: Looks interesting, although I figured that even a Chromebook would happily decode 720p60 or even 1080p60 video at a fraction of that price. Perhaps I was wrong...